# Ошибка OpenCV: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Tags: python, opencv

Пытаюсь отобразить видео с видеокамеры. Код:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Но выводится такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\users\Desktop\123.py", line 8, in <module>
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-_xlv4eex\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 3):

Нужно проверять, что возвращает `read`

Например:

```
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```